# how to get data from multi-dimensional array in laravel

Tags: arrays, laravel, multidimensional-array

I don't have  any idea how can i save this in my database
I have used dd($veriable[0]);
but can't get the data from arrays inside the array #items: array:2 [▼

My data is coming like

```
      +"id": 5484815
      +"title": "Camera"
      +"variants": array:1 [▼
        0 => {#1257 ▼
          +"product_id": 1546
          +"id": 548
```

stackoverflow says add more text i dont know what else i can add thats why i'm writing this to full fill the requirements
and stil they are saying that there is more code than text so i'm writing this line

Comment: please share your code here what do you get from array particular field or something else

Comment: I'm getting data of a product from Shopify store that is the output

Comment: #items: array:2 [▼
    0 => {#1261 ▼
      +"id": 8053022589247
      +"template_suffix": ""
      +"status": "active"
      +"published_scope": "web"
      +"tags": "camera, tech, video"
      +"admin_graphql_api_id": "7"
      +"variants": array:1 [▼
        0 => {#1257 ▶}
      ]
      +"options": array:1 [▼
        0 => {#1263 ▼
          +"id": 10232983060799
          +"name": "Title"
          +"position": 1
          +"values": array:1 [▶]
        }
      ]
      +"images": array:1 [▶]
      +"image": {#1256 ▶}
    }
    1 => {#1252 ▶}

Comment: i hope you got your correct answer

Comment: did you check this ?? it's working or not

Comment: i can't understand what you are trying to say

Comment: i think you are unable to understand what I'm trying to ask

Comment: I got your Question please share your Query which get outpost like this items: array:2 [▼ 0 => {#1261 ▼ +"id": 8053022589247 +"template_suffix": "" +"status": "active" +"published_scope": " @Abu Huaira

Comment: I got it right i was trying to get values from arrays inside an array without using foreach

Comment: you got correct answer ??

Comment: your problem is slove or not now ??

Comment: please check it's working !!

Answer (score 0):

Use the Collections provided by Laravel:

```
$items = collect($cart->items);
$reference_mails = $items->map(function($item){
    return $item['reference_mail'];
});
```